# Show that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\dfrac{(-1)^{n+1}(x+\sqrt{n})}{n}$ does not converge absolutely for $x\in [-1,1]$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis

Show that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\dfrac{(-1)^{n+1}(x+\sqrt{n})}{n}$ does not converge absolutely for $x\in [-1,1]$

Consider $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\large|\dfrac{(-1)^{n+1}(x+\sqrt{n})}{n}\large|=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\dfrac{x+\sqrt{n}}{n}$ for $x\in [-1,1]$.

Let $a_n = \dfrac{x+\sqrt{n}}{n}$.

How could I come up with a sequence $b_n <a_n$ for all $x\in [-1,1]$ such that $\sum b_n$ diverges?

Answer (score 1):

(1) First way:  For any $\;x\in[-1,1]\;,\;\;\{a_n\}\;$ is positive monotone non-ascending to zero, so

$$\left.\int\limits_1^\infty\frac{x+\sqrt t}tdt=x\log t-2\sqrt t\right|_1^\infty\;\;\leftarrow \;\text{not finite}$$

and thus the series diverges.

(2) Second way:

$$\begin{align*}\forall \;x\in [0,1]&\;:\;\;\frac{x+\sqrt n}n\ge\frac1{\sqrt n}\\{}\\
\forall x\in [-1,0)&\;:\;\;\frac{x+\sqrt n}n\ge\frac{-1+\sqrt n}{n}=\frac{n-1}{n\left(\sqrt n+1\right)}\ge\frac{n-1}{n^2}\end{align*}$$

and in both cases our series' general term is minorized by a term of a series that diverges.